# Build a runnable .jar or an exe with various resources - How?

Tags: java, maven, jar, build, libraries

I need your help / advice.
Basically I programmed a little game, this game has a lot of resources and different Libraries. Some Libraries are native libraries. Some are from maven (like slick2d which i used) and some are locally saved on my drive because i could not access them via maven.

Now I'd like to generate a runnable .jar to obviously easily start my little game, what's the best way to generate a .jar with those various dependencies stated above? I tried a lot of stuff like jarsplicer, mvn package and some other stuff. I was googling a lot and read about that you could write an extractor to archieven my goal.

Is this really neccessary? I just wanted to get some feedback of ppl who are more experienced than me regarding this task. If you need I can surely provide more information like project hierachy, used libraries etc.

So far I always ended up getting a jar ~20 mb big, incapable of starting, or maybe it is starting but not running the main method it should be.

Thanks for any advices / help!

Comment: If you want to distribute your game then you must ensure all the resources are with in the jar itself. And it is always a better practice than to keep resources scattered in your filesystem. And in case of libraries , then should be included with your jar too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second @Rahul's comment.

You can use the [Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/):

> *... to aggregate the project output along with its dependencies, modules, site documentation, and other files into a single distributable archive.*

Re *"incapable of starting"* see `<mainClass>` on its [Usage page, Creating an Executable JAR.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html#Creating_an_Executable_JAR)

Comment: Thanks, ill check this out as soon as i have some spare time.

Comment: I managed to create a JAR for my server, it's using kryonet and javafx for a GUI. 

I can't create a jar for my client tho. Is this plugin considering libraries which are not in maven as well? Because i stated i have some libraries locally on my drive?

Comment: I got a step further, I think the problem is that i have a local repository which is not integrated into my pom.xml , furthermore this local repository contains natives which i have to integrate into my pom.xml as well. I read about various maven plugins but it's quite confusing right now